# The page is not load completely when call onPageFinished()

Tags: java, android, android-webview, webpage-screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of a web view after the page loading finished. So I try to add the `getSnapShot()` in `onPageFinished()`, but when call the `getSnapShot()`, the page is not loaded. So the picture of snapshot is blank.

And I load a local html file url, so I believe there is no redirect.

I also tried to make `MyWebView extends WebView`, override `onDraw()`, add a callback listener to call `getSnapShot()` at `onDraw()` process.  But still not working.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        // will get a blank picture
        getSnapshot();
    }
});
```

Comment: you try without webview? maybe you are  it is incorrect code using

Comment: getSnapshot() is a method of taking screenshot, familiar with your code. But the screenshot is blank when I call it in onPageFinished(), (I tried use a button to take screenshot manually when page displayed, it works out. But I want automatically take screenshot)....

Answer (score 1):

Try this code;

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
        Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),
        picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas( b );

         picture.draw( c );
         FileOutputStream fos = null;
         try {

       fos = new FileOutputStream( "your_directory_screenshot.jpg" );
          if ( fos != null )
         {
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

      fos.close();
               }
         }
        catch( Exception e )
      {}
    }
});
```